# How to simulate click event on DIV element with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

http://services.groupes.be/ibrunet/ibrunet.aspx?lg=NL

I am trying to simulate click events on DIV elements with `class="x-grid-cell-inner"`(with text Ibrunet, Signaletiek..)

First I inserted jQuery.

```
javascript:var s=document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('src', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js');document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);alert("loaded");void(s);
```

Then I tried this

```
var bedragenDivClass = "x-grid-cell-inner ";
var bedragenDivText = "Bedragen";
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName(bedragenDivClass);
for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(divs[i].innerText.localeCompare(bedragenDivText) == 0){
        alert("found");
    };
};
```

And I've got referrence to this DIV but then I tried several different functions to trigger click event without any success

```
.trigger()

.triggerHandler()

.click()
```

When I open Chrome Dev Tools I can see several handler bounded to that DIV but I dont know how to trigger them

Unusual thing is that I could simulate click on input elements on right panel

```
var contractTypeInputId = "Cmb_Type_Contrat_Ibrunet_PLus-inputEl";
var contractTypeInput = document.getElementById(contractTypeInputId);
contractTypeInput.click();
```

Also I could click on elemenets of that input that show after script click it.

Since those DIV's don't have id attribute and I thought I need id to trigger the event I've gave them inside Dev Tools and I could retrieve it after but again no success with triggering onClick event.

The strangest thing is when I run something like this:

```
$("div").click();
```

I can see many DIV's beign clicked but those with that class I specified are not affected.

If I can trigger the event as simple as clicking on that DIV why I failed simulating it?

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery

```
$(".-grid-cell-inner:contains(Ibrunet, Signaletiek)").click(function () {
 alert(1);
});
$(".-grid-cell-inner:contains(Ibrunet, Signaletiek)").trigger("click");
```

Comment: This didn't worked.
Maybe because div class is x-grid-cell-inner.
Even after I changed it nothing happened.
Probably wrong selector but still when I did this:

$(".x-grid-cell-inner").click(function(){
 alert(1);
});
$(".x-grid-cell-inner").trigger("click");

it found around 20-30 matches but none of them actually changed right panel and that is what is happening when I manually click on them.
It should switch tabs.

Comment: can you make a js fiddle for that? then i can help yu